# how do I split 1 str column into 2 columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, split, multiple-columns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3qo6.png)

```
df['business location'] #column i want to split into 2 columns : 
df['longitude'] #and
df['latitude']

df[['longitude','latitude']] = sf['Business Location'].str.split(',')
```

is giving me error:
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

how do I split?

Comment: try using `expand=True` i.e `df.join(df['Business Location'].str.split(',',expand=True).rename(columns={0 : 'long', 1 : 'lat'}))`

Comment: agree with the dupe make sure you look at the highest rated answer not the accepted one.

Answer (score -1):

This will work

```
df.assign(
      longitude=lambda x: x['Business Location'].str.split(',').str[0],
      latitude=lambda x: x['Business Location'].str.split(',').str[1])
```